# php syntax error on line 5

Tags: php

```
    <?php

$vc=$_POST['versioncode'];

if ($vc == 1.0.2){

echo 1;  // for correct version code

} else {

echo 0; // for incorrect version code

}
?>
```

I get this error. Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_DNUMBER in /hermes/bosweb26b/b865/ipg.synamegamescom/giveaway/versioncheck.php on line 5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to quote `1.0.2` as it is not a valid number (`T_DNUMBER`):

```
if ($vc == '1.0.2') {
  ...
}
```

I'd also encourage you to look at [`version_compare()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.version-compare.php)

Answer (score 3):

`if ($vc == 1.0.2){`

`1.0.2` is not a valid number. Probably you need to compare it as a string `'1.0.2'` like:

```
if ($vc == '1.0.2'){
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use: `if ($vc == "1.0.2") { ... }`

Comment: I think you mean `if ($vc == "1.0.2")...` ?

Comment: yes, bad edit of mine, thanks. I added the brackets later and carried the `"` along.

Answer (score 0):

1.0.2 is not a valid number. You should treat it as a string instead:

```
if ($vc == '1.0.2') {...}
```